# objective-c NSUserNotification header title

Tags: objective-c, nsusernotification

Does any one know which value is being used for the title in the header bar for the system notification that is sent from the application?

Let's assume my app is named "My.app Name", the header title just says "My".

I'm talking about this field:

[image]

Tried changing Product Name in Build Settings to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The title you are trying to change is linked with your Applications name,
to change its name after creating it, you might double-click (slowly) your Application in the Project Navigator.